# More parallel processes than available processors in pathos

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pathos

I used to be able to run 100 parallel process this way:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def run_in_parallel(some_list):
    proc = []
    for list_element in some_list:
        time.sleep(20)
        p = Process(target=main, args=(list_element,))
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)
    for p in proc:
        p.join()

run_in_parallel(some_list)
```

but now my inputs are a bit more complicated and I'm getting "that" pickle error. I had to switch to pathos.

The following minimal example of my code works well but it seems to be limited by the number of threads. How can I get pathos to scale up to 100 parallel process? My cpu only has 4 cores. My processes are idling most of the time but they have to run for days. I don't mind having that "time.sleep(20)" in there for the initialization.

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool

input = zip(itertools.repeat((variable1, variable2, class1), len(some_list)), some_list)

p = Pool()
p.map(main, input)
```

edit:
Ideally I would like to do p = Pool(nodes=len(some_list)), which does not work of course.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the `pathos` author.  I'm not sure I'm interpreting your question correctly -- it's a bit easier to interpret the question when you have provided a minimal working code sample.  However...

Is this what you mean?

```
>>> def name(x):
...   import multiprocess as mp
...   return mp.process.current_process().name
... 
>>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
>>> p = Pool(ncpus=10)
>>> p.map(name, range(10))
['PoolWorker-1', 'PoolWorker-2', 'PoolWorker-3', 'PoolWorker-4', 'PoolWorker-6', 'PoolWorker-5', 'PoolWorker-7', 'PoolWorker-8', 'PoolWorker-9', 'PoolWorker-10']
>>> p.map(name, range(20))
['PoolWorker-1', 'PoolWorker-2', 'PoolWorker-3', 'PoolWorker-4', 'PoolWorker-6', 'PoolWorker-5', 'PoolWorker-7', 'PoolWorker-8', 'PoolWorker-9', 'PoolWorker-10', 'PoolWorker-1', 'PoolWorker-2', 'PoolWorker-3', 'PoolWorker-4', 'PoolWorker-6', 'PoolWorker-5', 'PoolWorker-7', 'PoolWorker-8', 'PoolWorker-9', 'PoolWorker-10']
>>>
```

Then, for example, if you wanted to reconfigure to only use 4 cpus, you can do this:

```
>>> p.ncpus = 4      
>>> p.map(name, range(20))
['PoolWorker-11', 'PoolWorker-11', 'PoolWorker-12', 'PoolWorker-12', 'PoolWorker-13', 'PoolWorker-13', 'PoolWorker-14', 'PoolWorker-14', 'PoolWorker-11', 'PoolWorker-11', 'PoolWorker-12', 'PoolWorker-12', 'PoolWorker-13', 'PoolWorker-13', 'PoolWorker-14', 'PoolWorker-14', 'PoolWorker-11', 'PoolWorker-11', 'PoolWorker-12', 'PoolWorker-12']
```

I'd worry that if you have only 4 cores, but want 100-way parallel, that you may not get the scaling that you think. Depending on how long the function you want to parallelize takes, you might want to use one of the other `pools`, like: `pathos.threading.ThreadPool` or a MPI-centric pool from `pyina`.

What happens with only 4 cores and 100 processes is that the 4 cores will have 100 instances of python spawned at once... so that may be a serious memory hit, and the multiple instances of python on a single core will compete for cpu time... so it might be best to play with the configuration a bit to find the right mix of resource oversubscribing and any resource idling.